# Laravel: No such file or directory

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Пытаюсь на сайте сделать обрезание фотографии с помощью плагина `ImgAreaSelect` *jQuery*.

Вывожу изображение на экран, выбираю кусок картинки, который нужно вырезать, и с помощью формы отправляю данные:

```
<p>
  <img id="photo" src="{{Auth::user()->photo}}" alt="" title="" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px;" width="600px" height="400px">
</p>
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'user.redPhoto']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="w" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Редактировать фото">
{!! Form::close() !!}
function preview(img, selection) {
        var scaleX = 70 / (selection.width || 1);
        var scaleY = 70 / (selection.height || 1);
        $('#photo + div > img').css({
            width: Math.round(scaleX * 600) + 'px',
            height: Math.round(scaleY * 400) + 'px',
            marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
            marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px',
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "{{Auth::user()->photo}}";
        $('<div><img src="{{Auth::user()->photo}}" style="position:relative;"><div>').css({
            float: 'left',
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: '70px',
            height: '70px',
        }).insertAfter($('#photo'));

        $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({
            x1: 120, y1:90, x2:280, y2: 210,
            aspectRatio: '1:1',
            handles: true,
            onSelectChange: preview,
            onSelectEnd: function (image, selection) {
                $('input[name=x1]').val(selection.x1);
                $('input[name=y1]').val(selection.y1);
                $('input[name=x2]').val(selection.x2);
                $('input[name=y2]').val(selection.y2);
                $('input[name=w]').val(selection.width);
                $('input[name=h]').val(selection.height);
            }
        });
    });
```

Данные формы отправляю через маршрут в контроллер в созданный метод:

```
Route::post('index.html', ['uses' => 'UserController@redPhoto',
  'as' => 'user.redPhoto']);
```

В  методе обращаюсь к файлу, который уже имеется в директории, и его пытаюсь заменить на новый, уже измененный:

```
public function redPhoto() {
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $filename = $user->photo;
    $new_filename = $user->photo;

    list($current_width, $current_height) = getimagesize($filename);

    $x1 = \Input::get('x1');
    $y1 = \Input::get('y1');
    $x2 = \Input::get('x2');
    $y2 = \Input::get('y2');
    $w = \Input::get('w');
    $h = \Input::get('h');

    $crop_width = 70;
    $crop_height = 70;

   $new = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_width, $crop_height);
    $current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($new, $current_image, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $crop_width, $crop_height, $w, $h);
   imagejpeg($new, $new_filename, 95);

    return view('layouts.welcome');
}
```

И в этот момент *laravel* присылает ошибку:

> ErrorException in UserController.php line 209:
>
> No such file or directory

В чём может быть причина ошибки?

Comment: причина ошибки может быть в том, что `$user->photo` - это не абсолютный путь к файлу, а его URL или релативный путь

Comment: Что в 209 строке в UserController.php за код находится?

Comment: В 209 строке расположен вот этот код: list($current_width, $current_height) = getimagesize($filename); @Visman

Comment: Если ставить абсалютный путь выдает это: 'Failed to open http://arena.local/uploads/avatars/8.1438179120.jpg (cannot open a url stream for write/append operation: http://arena.local/uploads/avatars/8.1438179120.jpg)' @zhenyab

Comment: Так Вы пытаетесь открыть файл, который удаленный и не находится на сервере? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Почему же, нет он находиться в директории public '/uploads/avatars/8.1438179120.jpg' , я его хочу просто заменить на негоже только с измененными размерами. @zhenyab

Comment: Ну так и укажите абсолютный путь к файлу по полной программе.

Comment: Я поставил: "$filename = "http://arena.local".$user->photo;
        $new_filename = "http://arena.local".$user->photo;" @zhenyab

Comment: И он вернул мне следующую ошибку: 'Failed to open http://arena.local/uploads/avatars/8.1438179120.jpg (cannot open a url stream for write/append operation: http://arena.local/uploads/avatars/8.1438179120.jpg)' @zhenyab

Comment: А у новой ошибки все та же самая 209 строка?

Comment: Теперь ссылается на 224 строку 'ErrorException in UserController.php line 224' т.е. на 'imagejpeg($new, $new_filename, 95)' и я не понимаю вчем причина. @Visman

Comment: Думаю ошибка из-за того на запись, что вы пишите в тот же файл, который открыт на чтение. Попробуйте перед imagejpeg($new, $new_filename, 95); поставить команду imagedestroy($current_image);

Comment: К сожилению результат это не дало, он также выдате ошибку: 'ErrorException in UserController.php line 225:
Failed to open http://arena.local/uploads/avatars/8.1438179120.jpg (cannot open a url stream for write/append operation: http://arena.local/uploads/avatars/8.1438179120.jpg)' и ссылается на строку 'imagejpeg($new, $new_filename, 95);' @Visman

Comment: Если имя нового файла  задать так $new_filename = "arena.local".$user->photo.".tmp"; будет ошибка?

Comment: Тоже самое только путь сменился в ошибке: 'ErrorException in UserController.php line 224:
Failed to open http://arena.local/uploads/avatars/8.1438179120_copy.jpg (cannot open a url stream for write/append operation: http://arena.local/uploads/avatars/8.1438179120_copy.jpg)' @Visman

Comment: Возможно у вас папка на запись закрыта для этого пользователя (php под которым запущен).

Comment: Но ведь файлы я могу добавлять в этот каталог от данного пользователя. @Visman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что пхп это не браузер, и ему наплевать как выглядит урл в браузере, ему нужен местная дорога, как в виндоусе есть `http://localhost` и `z:\wamp\`.

Для пхп нужно второе, поэтому он ругается когда вы отдаете ему неправельное место где хранится файл.

зная где находится публичный корель сайта, мы ставим место куда записали, проводим через "очиститель" и он выдаст что-то в виде:

```
/home/site/laravel/public/uploads/.../image.jpg
```

что и будет правельное место для изображения.

попробуйте так:

```
$filename = realpath(public_path() . $user->photo);
```

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь. :) @Maximilian Prepl